# It show the increase(s)

Tags: word-usage, plural-forms, singular-vs-plural, singular

Would it  be correct (and why?) to use a plural form in a sentence like:

> The data shows the increase**s** in traffic for different things.

I would think that a singular noun may be better, because we are talking about one thing (the increase) many different times. Also if I had to use a plural, I'd say:

> The data shows increases in traffic for different things.

Without the "*the*"

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence would be more applicable to the specific data, as in, it would give a detailed description of the increases.

The second sentence is more apt for a summary of the data.

The *the* is used here in the first sentence to indicate specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Without context, it's hard to actually answer your question.

Generally, both are correct.

If you are talking about a singular increase, then it may be better to use the article **an**, as in `The data shows an increase in traffic`

Answer (score -1):

**Increase** is correct, because 'increases' implies a multitude of something; it can be compared with when you would use 'many' instead of 'much'. In other words, it's because 'traffic' is a single entity (it's never 'traffics' and can't be counted). You can say 'much traffic' but not 'many traffic', therefore you would say increase.

Comment: I disagree. Both are equally correct but have different meaning. See Chowdhury's answer for reference.